# Retrieve email ID of a recipient from mail client using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I am working on an email marketing solution. In this application I am sending mass mail to 1000 recipient with a link attached to download a document. My question is how do I capture the email address of the recipient who have downloaded the attachment.

I am able to track the IP address of the recipient but I am not finding a way to capture the Email ID of the recipient who has downloaded the file.

Comment: Can you give us some information about the way you're trackings IPs and what has you done so far? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG: yup! It's not a great question, and would be off-topic these days, but anything that is on the site is ripe for an edit. (I do try to close o/t stuff, but in general o/t flags will expire on stuff this old before other folks see them).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to provide access through a download page. Send a link as follows:

`http://mysite.com/downloads/12345/myfile.doc` - where 12345 is the ID of the recipient.

Use URL Rewrite or a similar module, to intercept the request, and redirect to a download page. This page can parse the ID, and log it somewhere, and then can continue on to present the file itself to the recipient.

There numerous variants on this theme - the key things is to put the ID soemwhere in the URL and pick it out when recipients request the file.

Streaming File to browser: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654

URL Rewrite: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite